# Local repository for magento modules

Tags: magento2

there is a task to create a local repository for selling your own modules, there is also a requirement that the client has access to a specific module, and not the entire local repository
I plan to use Satis for this, but the question arose how to authenticate the user if he enters composer require, maybe someone has encountered such a task and can explain how you can add a token to the module on the side of the local repository, and that when the composer request requires its input.

Answer (score 0):

Satis does not have a built-in mechanism to authenticate users, it is just a very simple alternative to Packagist without user management. However, you can set up an HTTP Basic Auth configuration in your webserver to "protect" the Satis instance. You can then manage the user credentials via HTTP Basic Auth configuration. If you want Satis plus a fancy Admin UI to manage the package configuration, Satisfy might be worth a try: https://github.com/ludofleury/satisfy

The downside of Satis & Satisfy is that all users will see all your packages. This might not be wanted. If you are looking for a bit more complex setup Repman might be worth a try: https://github.com/repman-io/repman
In Repman you can create organisations (customers), define access tokens, and configure packages. The downside is, it's a bit more complex to set up, e.g. it needs a database and some background workers to be active whilst Satis/Satisfy only needs access to the filesystem.